# Ubuntu Server 14.04 Trusty Tahr installer requires Internet access to install

Tags: internet

A picture shall do some of the talking:

[image]

This is related to my earlier question at StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384678/scripting-the-renewable-permission-for-internet-connection

After setting up keyboard I'm required to detect network hardware and conf it but the Internet setup here requires renewing the permission to use it, which isn't possible without any browser; permission is per computer. Conffing is no problem, but then the problems start cuz there's no connection like I said, and without choosing a mirror I can't get further, and choosing a mirror can't get further cuz of lack of Internet, tried many times with different mirrors. Worse yet, it wants to download installer components that are in the image, http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso

I have no idea what to ask, so I'll just say: since the installer requires Internet access that I don't have, how do I install ?

Comment: You should ask a question (you haven't yet!) in real, understandable english and consider the site's list of valid [topics](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) - this is clearly not related to professional system administration.

Comment: @SvW: Understandable English ? You can't be serious. And what is this question then ? Those lists make no sense, and I read it.

Comment: The most important part on the list of [valid topics](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) is the **professional capacity** thing. Anyway, I just sent the Ubuntu 14.04 installer through a non-networked VM install and it finished without a problem from the full DVD image. You just have to tell it to NOT use the network and don't install updates during the install. You then don't need to select mirrors and everything is fine.

Comment: @rautamiekka If the list of valid topics for a site makes no sense to you, chances are the site is not the right place for you to post your question.

Comment: What does migrating to the correct place mean then ? 'I don't know, such thing haven't existed for thousands of years' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked in environments where even the sysadmin staff couldn't get past the mandatory-login internet portal. It's annoying, but you work with it.

We had a proxy-server we could use to forward such non-browser traffic through if we really needed it. The proxy provided logging of who accessed what, and was restricted to the network segments that only we had access to. It helped some, but it required that whatever we were doing supported proxies (most stuff did).

Anyway, internet-free installs can be done. Be sure to download the full DVD-image installer (it was CD images back when I was in that kind of environment, but the theory is still the same) and skip the config-network and apply-updates stages; they're not critical.

Once you have a base install in place, you can configure the proxy information for the update system. A better solution would be to host updates locally through `apt-mirror`, as it minimizes the work the proxy has to do and reduces the number of systems that need unauthenticated internet access.

Comment: Ubuntu dropped DVD images many releases ago.

Comment: @rautamiekka I don't see DVD sized installs, but I do see the CD-sized ones I was definitely using for no-net installs. http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/14.04/release/

Comment: That did it. Wonder why they have to make not so much smaller image which, at least for me, required Internet, when it was well possible before to install offline.

Comment: Chosen as the answer not cuz of the answer itself but the comment.

Comment: @rautamiekka the alternative image did not work for me either. I have not noticed any difference apart from the file name.

Comment: The only way to do a fully offline release is: download desktop version, boot into it, make a mirror of the respistory, then disconnect from internet and connect to private network with server, serve the repository via http via apache, then boot up the server install.... crazy. Ubuntu has a long history of being un-friendly to state alone installation, but at least you could always install a basic system and then connect to a repository on your own harddisk. But to require the repsostiroy over HTTP is getting ridiculous...